# How to return value from a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, async-await

I am calling a function that uses async/await. This function will get a string in the **const getinfo**

How can I return this "getinfo" string when calling the function like below?

```js
oneFunction("hello")
```

```js
oneFunction("hello")



function oneFunction(info) {

    (async function () {
        try {

            const getinfo = await somefunction(info)

        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    })()
}
```

Comment: That inner IIFE makes no sense. You should just make `oneFunction` the `async` function.

Comment: @Bergi when I look at the example now, I beleive you actually are right. I could in this case just use oneFunction as it is. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the immediately invoking function expression and instead `return` the function. Inside the try block return `getInfo`.

For this example `somefunction` is returning a promise which is resolved after 3 secs. Since `async` will return a promise you can get the value inside a `then`

```js
function oneFunction(info) {

  async function inner() {
    try {

      const getinfo = await somefunction(info);
      return getinfo;

    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

  return inner()
}

function somefunction(val) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve('Value from aysnc ' + val)
    }, 3000);
  })
}

oneFunction("hello").then((data) => {
  console.log(data)

})
```